# Difference between "By.partialLinkText" and "By.LinkText" in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I tried to find a element based on the Text i can see on screen on the Wikipedia page. Now, firstly i tried `driver.findElement(By.LinkText("English"));` with no results. 
But then i tried the code below with `driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("English"));` instead and it worked.
Can someone explain me based on that wikipedia page, why is that? Because the example is really simple and i don't know why `driver.findElement(By.LinkText("English"));` does not work?

```
driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.org");
WebElement link;
link = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("English"));
link.click();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name says it all. 
**LinkText**:  it returns elements with an exact match of the given text
**PartialLinkText** returns elements which include the given text

I have looked at http://www.wikipedia.org and I saw that the Link also includes other text elements:

> ```
> <a ... > 
>    <strong>English</strong> 
>    <small>
>       <bdi dir="ltr">5&nbsp;472&nbsp;000+</bdi>
>       <span>articles</span>
>    </small>
> </a>
> ```

That's why it will not find the text because it expects only "English"

Comment: Doesn't  include a space or other character?

Comment: good question, when i inspect the element with Firebug, it says `<strong>English</strong>`. So i guess there are no space or other character

Comment: Which browser are you using for the tests?

Comment: the browser is firefox

Comment: I have looked at the page and I see that the Link also includes other text:
<strong>English</strong>
<small><bdi dir="ltr">5&nbsp;472&nbsp;000+</bdi> <span>articles</span></small> 
That's why it will not find the Text because it expects only English.

Comment: so that is the reason why it does not work with `driver.findElement(By.LinkText("English"));`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154599/discussion-between-koen-meijer-and-suppe).

Comment: These methods only work on A (hyperlink) tags so these examples don't apply.

Comment: The given tags are inside the link tag. I've changed the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

By.LinkText :- Search for exact text which present inside it.

By.partialLinkText:- Search for similar text which is present inside it.

Comment: Yeah, but "English" is the exact text and it did not work!

Answer (score 1):

You could have just used the id instead. If there is an id present I almost always used that over anything else.

```
link = driver.FindElement(By.Id("js-link-box-en"));
```

Answer (score 0):

English is a part of text value in that  tag. The complete link text is breaking into 2 inner tags as shown in the DOM structure,

```
<small>
      <bdi dir="ltr">5&nbsp;472&nbsp;000+</bdi>
      <span>articles</span>
</small>
```

In UI:
"English 
5876000+ articles"

[Which I shown it in the attached image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Zgn.png)